# How to fix "cannot read property 'map' of undefine" in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm passing a map to all my posts variable so that all my posts can appear as a single post, but it kept bringing up the error

I have tried solving it using the Reactjs Documentation from the react website, it shows almost the same code as mine.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import PostItem from './PostItem';

class PostFeed extends Component {
  render() {
    const { posts }  = this.props;
    const list = posts.map((post) => <PostItem 
            key={post._id} 
            posts={post}
         />
        );
    return (
        {list}
    );
  }
}

PostFeed.propTypes = {
  posts: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default PostFeed;
```

I expect every posts to appear as a single post from the `postItem` component

[image: Console output]

Comment: put condition like this :
const list = posts && posts.map((post) => <PostItem.....

Comment: please add code where you invoke `<PostFeed ...`

Comment: In adding to condition in above comment above, u can check if list is an array to use map function. `Array.isArray(list);` and should check for length as well.

Answer (score 0):

posts is probably result of an async action and its value is not available at the time that your function is doing its job. So it should have a default value or be checked before that has a value.do this:

```
if(this.props.posts && Array.isArray(this.props.posts) && this.props.posts.length > 0)
//then map
```

Comment: Should probably also check for length. You're avoiding the error, but if `posts` is empty you're still left with no data.

Answer (score 0):

The error means, when your `PostFeed` mounts for first time at that time `props` are not available, so the error.

You can check if data available, like,

```
let list = "Loading...";
if(posts && posts.length > 0){
  list = posts.map((post) => <PostItem key={post._id} posts={post} /> );
}
```

Comment: You don't need `> 0`, just `posts.length` (unless you think it's clearer or something like that?).